# Getting This project doesn't have any tests error in cc.net

Tags: vb.net, msbuild, nunit, cruisecontrol.net, watin

I am getting the following Warnings while running tests using cc.net

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets (,): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework, Version=2.4.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\srce\TP\ITTests\ITTests\ITTests\Tests.vb (1,): warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'NUnit.Framework' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.
C:\srce\TP\ITTests\ITTests\ITTests\kingTests.vb (1,): warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'NUnit.Framework' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Not run: 0, Time: 0 seconds
No Tests Run 
This project doesn't have any tests

Any idea why? as All paths seems to be correct

Kind Regards

Comment: is this supposed to be a question?

Comment: Yes, I am getting these warnings and I dont know why as paths are correct.

Comment: Well update the question, with a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install NUnit on the CC.NET server?

Comment: This is a compile-time error. Does this work when you build outside of CruiseControl.NET? What are you calling to do the build in CC.NET (what is in your <tasks> block?)

Answer (score 0):

The first place to check is your CCNET log file. (Assuming it's enabled)
Logs can be found in the same folder as the cruise control program.
It may show that you're trying to test a DLL that does not exist. (perhaps you're trying to test a Debug DLL instead of a Release DLL or vice versa)